# Dell Inspiron 14-3452 BIOS refuses to boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dell, inspiron

After installing Ubuntu 15.10 x64 (I also tried 14.04 x32), whenever I booted, it told me:

> Your system seems to be having trouble starting. Dell SupportAssist is scanning your hardware for a possible cause.

Is there a fix for this?

EDIT: I'm about to give up. There is no setting in the BIOS to make this work, I can't reinstall Windows to update the BIOS, and I've tried all restorative and formatting applications on the Ubuntu live USB. Can anyone help me?

EDIT 2: Boot repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14272322/

Comment: This links might be helpful [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) - but I was told boot-repair might fail.

Comment: I had already tried boot-repair, and it didn't work. I'll have to try testdisk.

Comment: some guy today also suggested gparted - but I have not used it in erroneous occasions. Only to resize partitions

Comment: What would be the use of gparted to fix the problem?

Comment: Some guy today commented that if you have partition table issues, gparted has options to repair it... he also said you can check/repair a drive from live-cd with the fsck command - I have not tried both.

Comment: testdisk didn't work. I'm going to try gparted.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The installer wrote the boot partition back onto the installer drive, so the hard drive had no boot partition.

Comment: Are you now reinstalling the OS?

Comment: I think I found another problem. The BIOS may be looking for a disk partitioned with MBR, and I think it was partitioned as something else. I'm reinstalling now after repartitioning as MBR.

Answer (score 1):

In the bios look for a setting that says something like 'enable load ROM'. Disable that. To be able to change it you might have to change the boot setting to uefi or legacy, I forgot which one